# Is there an excel function to tell if a cell has a dependency?

Tags: excel, dependencies, predicate

Is there an excel function to tell if a cell has a dependency ?
basically input is the cell and returns true/false
(puting aside case when you use function like row, index, etc..)

thanks

Comment: Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Trace Precedents

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no built-in function for that.
You might want to take a look at:

Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Trace Dependents (Trace Precedents also)

You can do it with VBA functions: [excel.range.dependents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.dependents)